# Javascript/jquery equivalent of echoing (PHP) cookie value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a cookie named `myName`

In php, to print the cookie value, I can simply do

```
<?=$_COOKIE['myName']?>
```

The shortest I have found in JS is:

```
<script>
    document.write($.cookie('myName'));
</script>
```

Is there not a better/shorter way to do this? Maybe with JQuery?

I am quite new to JS and moving a site over from PHP for mobile Phonegap Build dev so can't use PHP

Comment: Isn't that already jQuery? Looks like it.

Comment: Please don't use `document.write`: it's 2014, not 2004. If you need to show something to a user, create some element (or take an existing one) and fill its text(Content) with the value to be shown.

Comment: That's the jQuery $.cookie plugin? To see the cookie you only have to do `document.cookie` -> http://jsfiddle.net/JDuLF/

Comment: Why do you want to write out the value of your cookie? If it is for debugging try console.log($.cookie('myName');

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Cookie plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) and get cookie just like

```
$.cookie("myName")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a plugin like jQuery $.cookie, you can do something like this

```
function getCookie(cookiename) {
    var cookiestring = RegExp(""+cookiename+"[^;]+").exec(document.cookie);
    return unescape(!!cookiestring ? cookiestring.toString().replace(/^[^=]+./,"") : "");
}

var value = getCookie('myName');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DV3th/)

Answer (score 0):

And what you will find very usefull is to use the console while debugging: write in your code:
console.log(document.cookie);

or

console.log($.cookie('myName'));

And see the results in the javascript console of your browser (easiest way: right click in your page, go to the last item which says "inspect element", and in the window that will open, go to the last tab, named "console".)

Answer (score -3):

use a self executing function

```
<script>
    (function(){document.cookie="username=test; expires=Fri, 28 Feb 2014 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";})();
</script>
```

check out more information on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)

Comment: This wont write the cookie to the page though, will it?

Comment: I dont think so.. where does it actually _print_ the value to the screen, like the OP asks?

Comment: @Dexter I agree, it doesn't. Misunderstood the question.